SSIS creates a text file with Data Flow Task, but gets "Access Denied" error during bulk insert task. Any ideas why?
I create a text file using an SSIS Data Flow Task, but when the package tries to read from the text file using a subsequent bulk insert task, an "Access Denied" error gets raised. This happens only when running the package within the Visual Studio 2022 IDE. Has anyone seen this and know a solution?
I made sure that I personally have read/write access to the file, since running the package in the Visual Studio IDE runs under my security context. Also, the package runs just fine on the server when executed from a SQL Server Agent job.

I have seen this with some packages and other files when debugging because the debugging locks the file.  Does it happen the very first time you open VS and run the package?  Or only on subsequent tries (and is the file name the same each time you run it)?  Could be stuck with a lock on the file if that is the case.

It seems to happen each time I run it while debugging.
